# ORA-00942. But the table exists in DBA_TABLES and DBA_OBJECTS

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Oracle Version: 11.2.0.1.0. I imported a schema from database dump. I am connecting as HR.
I am able to see a table via 'desc table_name'. When I query DBA_* objects, the output is ok.

But when doing insert, I get `ORA-00942`.

```
SQL> desc EMPLOYEE
 Name                                    Null?    Type
 --------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 EMPLOYEE_ID                             NOT NULL NUMBER(16)
 EMPLOYEE_NAME                           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(200 CHAR)

SQL> select count(*) from dba_tables where owner = 'HR'
  2  and table_name = 'EMPLOYEE'
  3  /

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1

SQL> select object_type, object_name, created from dba_objects where owner = 'HR' and object_name = 'EMPLOYEE'

OBJECT_TYPE     OBJECT_NAME              CREATED
TABLE           EMPLOYEE                 03-APR-15

SQL> insert into EMPLOYEE ( EMPLOYEE_ID, EMPLOYEE_NAME ) values ( 11,'x')
  2  /
insert into EMPLOYEE ( EMPLOYEE_ID, EMPLOYEE_NAME ) values ( 11,'x')
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Comment: Are you able to `select from EMPLOYEE` ?

Comment: Does the EMPLOYEE table exist in other schemas as well? (Possibly bug 9577583 or 16414430, or others... see support doc 9577583.8)

Answer (score 3):

This looks like bug 9577583, which affects 11.2.0.1, as well as some earlier versions. If you have access to My Oracle Support, look at [document ID 9577583.8](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=9577583.8).

The very high level synopsis, since I can't reproduce what that says in any detail, is that this can occur when identical objects appear in multiple schemas - you have the same `employee` table in the `hr` and `scott` schemas, for example - and Oracle gets confused about which object it's supposed to be looking at.

It's possible that flushing the shared pool and/or forcing a hard parse might resolve the issue, at least temporarily, but I don't have a base version to test that on; and you'd be better off patching if you're able to. You might want to raise a service request with Oracle first to verify that this is what you are seeing.

Answer (score 2):

what user are you running the insert as? unless you are connected as the "hr" user your code will need to look like this...

```
insert into HR.EMPLOYEE ( EMPLOYEE_ID, EMPLOYEE_NAME ) values ( 11,'x')
```

you need to include the schema name in the insert

Comment: Why is the schema-name not needed with _desc_?

Comment: I am connected as HR.

Comment: not entirely sure, it should be consistent. Maybe this isn't the answer but it would be the first thing i would try

Comment: could you post the create table statement so i can try this out

Comment: I modified the query to prefix schema name. Same result.

Comment: i have created the table and tried the insert and it all works ok, what version of Oracle and what OS are you running?

Comment: @davegreen100 - Sure there it is. But I am afraid that you will not be able to replicate the error. ( because I was not able to :-(               SQL> create table e ( employee_id number(16), employee_name varchar2(200))
  2  /

Table created.

SQL> insert into e select list_folder_id,folder_name from list_folder
  2  /

15274 rows created.

SQL> commit
  2  /

Commit complete.

SQL> insert into e values ( 222222, 'y')
  2  /

1 row created.

SQL> commit
  2  /

Commit complete.

SQL>

Comment: @davegreen100 - Oracle version is 11.2.0.1.0.

Comment: To add - the table was imported from a database dump.

Comment: Please add these details to your question... (using user HR, Oracle Version, from dump, ...)

Comment: @AlexPoole - yes, most likely looks to be a bug 9577583. Will patch my system and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

The table was base table for a MV ( materialized view ). Due to a bug if the MV LOG  is dropped using any method other than 'drop mv log' command, any subsequent DML will raise this error. The resolution is to use 'drop mv log' on such table. See Doc ID 1912363.1